# How to make recursive nested loops which use loop variables inside?

Tags: recursion, fortran, nested-loops

I need to make a nested loop with an arbitrary depth. Recursive loops seem the right way, but I don't know how to use the loop variables in side the loop. For example, once I specify the depth to 3, it should work like

```
count = 1 
for i=1, Nmax-2
    for j=i+1, Nmax-1
        for k=j+1,Nmax
            function(i,j,k,0,0,0,0....) // a function having Nmax arguments
            count += 1
        end
    end
end
```

I want to make a subroutine which takes the depth of the loops as an argument.

UPDATE:

I implemented the scheme proposed by Zoltan. I wrote it in python for simplicity.

```
count = 0;

def f(CurrentDepth, ArgSoFar, MaxDepth, Nmax): 
    global count;
    if CurrentDepth > MaxDepth:
        count += 1;
        print count, ArgSoFar;
    else:
        if CurrentDepth == 1:
            for i in range(1, Nmax + 2 - MaxDepth):
                NewArgs = ArgSoFar;
                NewArgs[1-1] = i;
                f(2, NewArgs, MaxDepth, Nmax);
        else:
            for i in range(ArgSoFar[CurrentDepth-1-1] + 1, Nmax + CurrentDepth - MaxDepth +1):
                NewArgs = ArgSoFar;
                NewArgs[CurrentDepth-1] = i;
                f(CurrentDepth + 1, NewArgs, MaxDepth, Nmax);

f(1,[0,0,0,0,0],3,5)
```

and the results are

```
1 [1, 2, 3, 0, 0]
2 [1, 2, 4, 0, 0]
3 [1, 2, 5, 0, 0]
4 [1, 3, 4, 0, 0]
5 [1, 3, 5, 0, 0]
6 [1, 4, 5, 0, 0]
7 [2, 3, 4, 0, 0]
8 [2, 3, 5, 0, 0]
9 [2, 4, 5, 0, 0]
10 [3, 4, 5, 0, 0]
```

There may be a better way to do this, but so far this one works fine. It seems easy to do this in fortran. Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: Could you tag the language please? With C++ templates may come to the rescue. With Java you probably should use a list. &c.

Comment: PS. I'm using fortran90.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define your function to have a `List` argument, which is initially empty

```
void f(int num,List argumentsSoFar){

  // call f() for num+1..Nmax
  for(i = num+1 ; i < Nmax ; i++){
    List newArgs=argumentsSoFar.clone();
    newArgs.add(i);
    f(i,newArgs);
  }
  if (num+1==Nmax){
     // do the work with your argument list...i think you wanted to arrive here ;)
  }

}
```

caveat: the stack should be able to handle `Nmax` depth function calls

Comment: Thank you, Zoltan! I need a bit more time to think this routine in fortran way. Sorry that I didn't put the language tag...

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you could do what you want.  This is pseudo-code, I haven't written enough to compile and test it but you should get the picture.

Define a function, let's call it `fun1` which takes *inter alia* an integer array argument, perhaps like this

```
<type> function fun1(indices, other_arguments)
    integer, dimension(:), intent(in) :: indices
    ...
```

which you might call like this

```
fun1([4,5,6],...)
```

and the interpretation of this is that the function is to use a loop-nest 3 levels deep like this:

```
do ix = 1,4
    do jx = 1,5
        do kx = 1,6
        ...
```

Of course, you can't write a loop nest whose depth is determined at run-time (not in Fortran anyway) so you would flatten this into a single loop along the lines of

```
do ix = 1, product(indices)
```

If you need the values of the individual indices inside the loop you'll need to *unflatten* the linearised index.  Note that all you are doing is writing the code to transform array indices from N-D into 1-D and *vice versa*; this is what the compiler does for you when you can specify the rank of an array at compile time.  If the inner loops aren't to run over the whole range of the indices you'll have to do something more complicated, careful coding required but not difficult.

Depending on what you are actually trying to do this may or may not be either a good or even satisfactory approach.  If you are trying to write a function to compute a value at each element in an array whose rank is not known when you write the function then the preceding suggestion is dead flat wrong, in this case you would want to write an `elemental` function. Update your question if you want further information.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It's good to know there are always varios ways to do the same thing!

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to achieve what you desire is based on the answer by High Performance Mark, but can be made more general:

```
subroutine nestedLoop(indicesIn)

  ! Input indices, of arbitrary rank
  integer,dimension(:),intent(in) :: indicesIn

  ! Internal indices, here set to length 5 for brevity, but set as many as you'd like
  integer,dimension(5) :: indices = 0

  integer :: i1,i2,i3,i4,i5

  indices(1:size(indicesIn)) = indicesIn

  do i1 = 0,indices(1)
    do i2 = 0,indices(2)
      do i3 = 0,indices(3)
        do i4 = 0,indices(4)
          do i5 = 0,indices(5)

            ! Do calculations here:
            ! myFunc(i1,i2,i3,i4,i5)

          enddo
        enddo
      enddo
    enddo
  enddo

endsubroutine nestedLoop
```

You now have nested loops explicitly coded, but these are 1-trip loops unless otherwise desired. Note that if you intend to construct arrays of rank that depends on the nested loop depth, you can go up to rank of 7, or 15 if you have a compiler that supports it (Fortran 2008). You can now try:

```
call nestedLoop([1])
call nestedLoop([2,3])
call nestedLoop([1,2,3,2,1])
```

You can modify this routine to your liking and desired applicability, add exception handling etc.

Comment: Thank you for the code, and pointing out a limitation I did not consider. I'm curious whether even the recursive loops are limited to 7 or 15 times.

Comment: I am sorry, I was being silly. The maximum rank limitation really applies to arrays only. I see now that you intend to call a function or a subroutine with certain number of arguments, so the maximum rank limitation would not apply there. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

From an OOP approach, each loop could be represented by a "Loop" object - this object would have the ability to be constructed while containing another instance of itself. You could then theoretically nest these as deep as you need to.

Loop1 would execute Loop2 would execute Loop3.. and onwards.